# Как реализовать live location на python в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Хочу сделать бота, который будет следит за мной. Если я отправлю ему свою гео позицию, чтобы раз в секунд 5-10 геопозиция обновлялась.

Мой нерабочий код:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["location"])
async def location(update):
    msg_id = message.message_id - 1
    await bot.edit_message_live_location(message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude, message.chat_id,
                                         message.message_id - 1)
```

PS Вот, ссылки помогут: https://core.telegram.org/api/live-location

Comment: какие ошибки пишет ваш "нерабочий код"?

Comment: Вот такую aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited типо нельзя отридоктировать, отправляю боту свою геопозицию через request_location

Comment: Как я знаю request_location, отправляет гео позицию, только один раз и ничего не отслеживает.

Comment: Я понял Stack overflow такая же бесполезная вещ как и Хабр что тут что там нигде нет помощи СПАСИБО

Comment: Я бы не был так категоричен. На подавляющее большинство вопросов тут есть ответы, зачастую очень хорошие, часто - даже больше одного. Поставьте себя на место отвечающих и, может быть, поймете, что не так с вашим вопросом? PS [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) PPS [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)